# Host Disk Usage: Warning message regarding disk usage

Tags: ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I've downloaded version HDF_3.0.2.0_vmware of the Hortonworks Sandbox. I am using VMWare Player version 6.0.7 on my laptop. Shortly after startup/logging into Ambari, I see this alert:

[image]

The message that is cut off reads: "Capacity Used: [60.11%, 32.3 GB], Capacity Total: [53.7 GB], path=/usr/hdp". I'd hoped that I would be able to focus on NiFi/Storm development rather than administering the sandbox itself, however it looks like the VM is undersized. Here are the VM settings I have for storage. How do I go about correcting the underlying issue prompting the alert?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue, it's about node partitioning and directories mounted for data under HDFS -> Configs -> Settings -> DataNode

You can check your node partitioning using below command-

```
lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

Mostly hdfs namenode or datanode directories point to root partitions. We can change thresholds values for alerts temporary and to have permanent solution we can add additional data directories.

Below links can he helpful to do the same.

- https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/21212/configure-storage-capacity-of-hadoop-cluster.html

Check from above link - I think your partitioning is wrong you are not using "/" for hdfs directory. If you want use full disk capacity, you can create any folder name under "/" example /data/1 on every data node using command "#mkdir -p /data/1" and add to it dfs.datanode.data.dir. restart the hdfs service.

- https://hadooptips.wordpress.com/2015/10/16/fixing-ambari-agent-disk-usage-alert-critical/
- https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/21687/how-to-increase-the-capacity-of-hdfs.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not currently able to replicate this, but based on the screenshots the warning is just that there is less space available than recommended. If this is the case everything should still work.

Given that this is a sandbox that should never be used for production, feel free to ignore the warning.

If you want to get rid fo the warning sign, it may be possible to do a quick fix by changing the warning treshold via the alert definition.

If this is still not sufficient, or you want to leverage more storage, please follow the steps outlined by @manohar